# Detectron2 - undefined symbol: _ZNK2at6Tensor7reshapeEN3c108ArrayRefIlEE

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, detectron

```
File /home/xyzUser/MyProject/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/detectron2/layers/deform_conv.py", line 11, in <module>
    from detectron2 import _C
ImportError: /home/xyzUser/MyProject/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/detectron2/_C.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK2at6Tensor7reshapeEN3c108ArrayRefIlEE
```

I am getting an import error while trying to work with detectron2. It was pre installed in my project. Cant uninstall detectron beacuse other tasks are using this package. does anyone know why this undefined symbol error is happening.